# Whats the best fit for continious delivery, Vagrant or Puppet,

Tags: continuous-integration, vagrant, puppet, continuous-deployment

At present I have to deploy the latest version of my application to a QA environment which is a painful and completely manual task.  Im looking at possibly using Puppet or Vagrant as a way to manage my infrastructure and spin up some virtual machines with all the components I need so I can run acceptance tests against the latest version of my software.  Im looking for something that integrates with my Bamboo and will teardown these machines when im finished with them.

Theres alot of talk about Vagrant, but it seems to me that you need to first prepare a VM before using Vagrant.  Is one better than the other or is anyone using both as part of there CI environment?.

Comment: Vagrant and Puppet solve different problems, they're not alternatives, but can play a key role in parts of your delivery pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Why or when you can use "and":

Puppet is a configuration management tool - forcing consistency and predictability across your cluster. Usually used in Staging/Production set ups where autoscaling of machines is used.

Vagrant is a simple framework for setting up virtual machines from a list of pre-configured "clean" installations. The first use case is a "playground" on your development machine.
Once Vagrant sets up the virtual machine it can provision it using Puppet to install all the prerequisites (e.g. your app) (just like it does in the production machines) and then you can test it.